# Align CSV columns in PyCharm

Tags: csv, intellij-idea, pycharm

Is there a way to view CSV in PyCharm with its columns automatically aligned?

For exemple this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

I know there's the 'Table Editor' option, but it leaves too much space between lines, it doesn't align numbers to the right and it doesn't let you zoom in the font:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your PyCharm is using the CSV-Plugin ([CSV Plugin at JetBrains Marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10037-csv) to provide the text and Table Editor functionalities.
The project page can be found at GitHub: [SeeSharpSoft /
intellij-csv-validator](https://github.com/SeeSharpSoft/intellij-csv-validator).

The Settings for this Plugin can be changed inside your PyCharm IDE Settings (File>Settings>Editor>Code Style>CSV/TSV/PSV).

To format my CSV files inside the Text Editor, I'm using f.e. those settings:

[image: CSV Settings]

The idea to format text based files could be very helpful - so far I found three different Python modules which could be used to achieve that:

- [Scolp](https://pypi.org/project/scolp/#description)
- [Tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/#description)
- [Columnar](https://pypi.org/project/Columnar/#description)

Additionally you can take a look into this Pycharm Plugin [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation).
It solves your requirement inside the Text Editor:

[image: Available Options to align Columns]